# More Inversion of Trigonometric Equations

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Can anyone invert

$y = a \cos(x) + b \sin(2x)$

to give $x = f(y)$? An exchange on 29 June 2017 said this was possible but I cannot find the solution. Also, is

$y = a \sin(x) + b \sin(2x)$

invertible in the same way?

Many thanks.

Comment: Consider using [Weierstrass substitution formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution)

Comment: Where was the "exchange on 29 June 2017"? Can you link to it in the question?